# Ionic serve with HTTPS secure connection

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I would like to know how to run ionic application with HTTPS secure connection. There is a HTTPS URL launched inside ionic application but it is not displayed. It gives an error. Please let me know how to run ionic serve with https://localhost:8100/.
Do I need to create root certificate, key file etc. for secure connection?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use the --ssl option

```
ionic serve -c --ssl --address='your IP address'
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/serve

Answer (score 2):

To run  **HTTPS** ionic serve, you will use the `--ssl` option. An example:

```
ionic serve --external --host="127.0.0.1" --port="8100" --ssl
```

Moreover, if you want to generate a self-signed certificate run this command:

```
ionic ssl generate
```

The default directory for the newly created private key & certificate is `.ionic/ssl/`. Hence, the paths are:

**Key:**    `./.ionic/ssl/key.pem`

**Cert:**   `./.ionic/ssl/cert.pem`

You could refer to *ionic* documentation anytime on the following link. https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/ssl-generate

Answer (score 1):

Use the following and just add your desired port.

ionic serve -p 8100 --ssl